# ElasticSearch fields limit in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My current config in docker-compose file:

```
elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - elastic:/var/lib/elastic/data
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=pass
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}:9200"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.0
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_kibana
    ports:
      - "${KIBANA_PORT}:5601"
```

I have a problem wit "Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded while adding new fields".
How I can incrase this limit through docker-compose file configuration.